# PHP set timeout for script with system call, set_time_limit not working

Tags: php, windows, linux, command-line

I have a command-line PHP script that runs a wget request using each member of an array with foreach. This wget request can sometimes take a long time so I want to be able to set a timeout for killing the script if it goes past 15 seconds for example. I have PHP safemode disabled and tried set_time_limit(15) early in the script, however it continues indefinitely. **Update:** Thanks to Dor for pointing out this is because set_time_limit() does not respect system() calls.

So I was trying to find other ways to kill the script after 15 seconds of execution. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to check the time a script has been running while it's in the middle of a wget request at the same time (a do while loop did not work). Maybe fork a process with a timer and set it to kill the parent after a set amount of time?

Thanks for any tips!

**Update:**
Below is my relevant code. $url is passed from the command-line and is an array of multiple URLs (sorry for not posting this initially):

```
foreach( $url as $key => $value){
    $wget = "wget -r -H -nd -l 999 $value";
    system($wget);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of "--timeout" and time().  Start off by figuring out how much time you have total, and lower the --timeout as your script runs.

For example:

```
$endtime = time()+15;
foreach( $url as $key => $value){
  $timeleft = $endtime - time();
  if($timeleft > 0) {
    $wget = "wget -t 1 --timeout $timeleft $otherwgetflags $value";
    print "running $wget<br>";
    system($wget);
  } else {
    print("timed out!");
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Note: if you don't use -t, wget will try 20 times, each waiting --timeout seconds.

Here's some example code using proc_open/proc_terminate (@Josh's suggestion):

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),
   2 => array("pipe", "w")
);
$pipes = array();

$endtime = time()+15;
foreach( $url as $key => $value){
  $wget = "wget $otherwgetflags $value";
  print "running $wget\n";
  $process = proc_open($wget, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
  if (is_resource($process)) {
    do {
      $timeleft = $endtime - time();
      $read = array($pipes[1]);
      stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $exeptions = NULL, $timeleft, NULL);
      if(!empty($read)) {
        $stdout = fread($pipes[1], 8192);
        print("wget said--$stdout--\n");
      }
    } while(!feof($pipes[1]) && $timeleft > 0);
    if($timeleft <= 0) {
      print("timed out\n");
      proc_terminate($process);
      exit(0);
    }
  } else {
    print("proc_open failed\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: proc_open/proc_terminate works well for me. Thanks everyone who contributed!

(Wish I could give Josh credit too, gave +1 instead).

Comment: @tehalive: Good solution! Don't worry about not "giving me credit", I already have +5 for my answer, your +1 brings it that much closer to another "Nice Answer" badge xD

Comment: @tehalive: just a note if you use my code for proc_open/proc_terminate, use the -q wget flag or it'll try to write to stderr.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the wget command line argument `--timeout` in addition to `set_time_limit()`.

Keep in mind `set_time_limit(15)` *restarts the timeout counter from zero* so don't call it inside a loop (for your purpose)

from `man wget`:

> --timeout=seconds
>
> Set the network
>   timeout to seconds seconds.  This is
>   equivalent to specifying
>   --dns-timeout, --connect-timeout, and --read-timeout, all at the same time.
>
> When interacting with the network,
>   Wget can check for timeout and abort
>   the operation if it takes too long. 
>   This prevents anomalies like hanging
>   reads and infinite connects.  The only
>   timeout enabled by default is a
>   900-second read timeout.  Setting a
>   timeout to 0 disables it altogether. 
>   Unless you know what you are doing, it
>   is best not to change the default
>   time-out settings.
>
> All timeout-related options accept
>   decimal values, as well as subsecond
>   values.  For example, 0.1 seconds is a
>   legal (though unwise) choice of
>   timeout.  Subsecond timeouts are
>   useful for checking server response
>   times or for testing network latency.

**EDIT:** OK. I see what you're doing now. What you should probably do is use [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead of `system`, and use the `time()`function to check the time, calling [proc_terminate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php) if wget tskes too long.

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately that doesn't work for my purposes. I apologize for not posting the relevant code, which would have made this more clear (see above updated question with code).
    
So the timeout argument for wget just sets that for each wget request, not the total script. So when I pass 5 URLs to the script, each with a timeout of 20, that's at least 100 seconds total, usually more because of the recursive option. Dor highlights below why set_time_limit() won't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can direct the output of the wget program to a file, which then returns immediately.
Also see:

> Note: The set_time_limit() function
>   and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time  only affect the
>   execution time of the script itself.
>   Any time spent on activity that
>   happens outside the execution of the
>   script such as system calls using
>   system(), stream operations, database
>   queries, etc. is not included when
>   determining the maximum time that the
>   script has been running. This is not
>   true on Windows where the measured
>   time is real.

Source: [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) @ php.net

Comment: +1. He needs to limit wget's execution time also, see my answer

Comment: @Josh: I think he meant to the PHP script: "so I want to be able to set a timeout for killing the script if it goes past 15 seconds for example". But noting about the wget timeout is also appreciated and helpful :)

Comment: Yes but as you said, set_time_limit has no effect on external commands like wget -- so to limit the total time of the script (including wget, because it's called from the script), wget must also be limited. That was my understanding of the question anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I think the far best way is to handle the killing in the command itself, at least on Linux (Ubuntu 17.10). No other means worked for me... `proc_terminate` from another answer worked but no output would be given.

In the example below, I adding a magic string that checks if your process is still running. If running longer than `$sec`, it kills the process immediately, leaving a note 'Timeout!'.

Like this, I am sure the command won't exceed timeout and I receive all the stdout/stderr I need.

```
$wget = "wget -r -H -nd -l 999 $value"; // your command

$sec = 5; // timeout in seconds
$cmd = $wget . " & ii=0 && while [ \"2\" -eq \"`ps -p $! | wc -l \" ]; do ii=$((ii+1)); if [ \$ii -gt ".($sec)."0 ]; then echo 'Timeout!';kill $!; break;fi; sleep 0.1; done"
system($cmd); // system call
```