# Determine how long a system(), pasthrus(), exec(), operation is taking in php

Tags: php, system, execution-time, passthru

Want to know how to determine how long a call to system(), passthru(), exec() (either of these) takes. For example. I use system() to call an external program, I would like to time how long it takes so that if it's taking too long I can kill it or do another operation on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = microtime(true);
system(....);
$end = microtime(true);

echo "system() call took ", $end - $start, " microseconds";
```

For the rest, check out [shell_exec() timeout management & exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407939/shell-exec-timeout-management-exec)

Comment: This actually gets how long system() took to run. Im looking for a counter of how long system() is taking so while it's still running I can say if it exceeded the time I set to it.