# How to stop execution of a function in php after a specific time?

Tags: php, linux

I have five `exec()` function in my script, which run one after another. I want `exec()` function stops its execution after 10 sec and next `exec()` function starts its execution.

```
<?php
  exec("/usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);
  foreach($uptime as $load){
    echo $load."<br />";
  }

  exec("/usr/local/bin/trun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);
  foreach($uptime as $load){
    echo $load."<br />";
  }

  exec("/usr/local/bin/drun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$uptime);
  foreach($uptime as $load){
    echo $load."<br />";
  }

   .......
  ?>
```

Comment: using ajax would be better solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [exec() with timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419122/exec-with-timeout)

Comment: @AmalMurali please give an example of `exec()` with timeout.

Comment: @user3422433: See the first answer in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

set_time_limit() does run globally,
but you may be able to set it locally,

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); 
function do()
{
    set_time_limit(10);   
    //  work
    set_time_limit(10);   

}

// ....
sleep(900);
// ....
do();  // only has 10 secs to run
// ....
sleep(900);
```