# exec() with timeout argument in php?

Tags: php, linux, timeout, exec

I have two exec() function with timeout argument.
eg:

```
<?php
exec("timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/trun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$t_uptime);
exec("timeout 5 /usr/local/bin/wrun 'uptime;ps -elf|grep httpd|wc -l;free -m;mpstat'",$t_uptime);
?>
```

Isn't working. I want `exec()` stop after 5 sec and next `exec()` function starts its execution.
Please correct this or give some alternative way to stop `exec()` function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419122/exec-with-timeout

Answer (score 0):

exec — Execute an external program

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )

exec() executes the given command.
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function instead- for more info read https://www.php.net/function.exec

```
 function PsExecute($command, $timeout = 5, $sleep = 2) {
        // First, execute the process, get the process ID
        $pid = PsExec($command);
        
        if( $pid === false )
            return false;
        
        $cur = 0;
        // Second, loop for $timeout seconds checking if process is running
        while( $cur < $timeout ) {
            sleep($sleep);
            $cur += $sleep;
            // If process is no longer running, return true;
            if( !PsExists($pid) )
                return true; // Process must have exited, success!
        }
        
        // If process is still running after timeout, kill the process and return false
        PsKill($pid);
        return false;
    }
```