# Terminating process running in background using php

Tags: php, shell, cmd

I am trying to execute a .exe file using exec() function on my webpage. It sometimes is entering infinite loops and the .exe file is never terminated preventing my php page from proceeding further.

```
exec('CodeFile.exe 1>temp\\OutputFile.txt<temp\\InputFile.txt');
unlink('CodeFile.exe');
```

Can any one help me out in ending the process when it enters infinite loop?

And i am using XAMPP running on Windows 10

Comment: Is CodeFile.exe something under your control? I would be more concerned about an app "sometimes entering infinite loops" and less about how to kill the process. In general, running exec() is a last resort solution.

Comment: Maybe you want some sort of [**timeout**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9419122/4577762)? See if anything from that page helps you.

Comment: None of them worked @FirstOne

Comment: Yes CodeFile.exe is C program compiled by me. @CharlieHills

Comment: Good stuff!  I'm sure nothing suspicious is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Since CodeFile.exe is a program under your control, I would focus on fixing that first. With rare exceptions, infinite loops do not represent intended or desired behavior. Looking for a timeout option is the equivalent of "sweeping the problem under the rug."

Clearly, CodeFile.exe is an important step in the process, otherwise you wouldn't have written it and made it part of your architecture. Your intention is that it complete before moving on with any subsequent processing. So if it occasionally runs off and never finishes, how can you continue from a broken and unknown state?

Comment: No, actually CodeFile.exe is an executable code typed by user  on my website. Sometimes they are ending up with loops. @Charlie Hills

Comment: I'm confused. Earlier you said, "Yes CodeFile.exe is C program compiled by me." What do you mean by "executable code typed by user"?

Comment: I want to conduct coding contests through my website.  So that's where user might enter any type of code

Comment: I hope I'm not reading that right: any person anywhere can upload any executable to your website and you'll just run it? That's exceedingly dangerous. If it's a coding contest, have them submit the source code along with InputFile.txt and OutputFile.txt. Don't blindly execute arbitrary user-supplied code.

Comment: I want to make something like them "codechef" "hackerrank" "hackerearth"

Answer (score 0):

```
    exec('CodeFile.exe 1>temp\\OutputFile.txt<temp\\InputFile.txt & timeout /t 10 & taskkill /im CodeFile.exe /f');
    unlink('CodeFile.exe');
```

This worked for me.:) Thank you @Charlie Hills and @FirstOne for your suggestions.