# Not able to capture the ouput of lscript into the file using PHP

Tags: php, tcl

I wanted to capture the output of the TCL script into the file using PHP.
I am able to capture `hello world` output to the file but when I am running long script which takes time and have large output then I am not.

**Here is my code:**

```
 <?php
 ob_start();
 passthru(' /path/to/file/helloworld ');
 $out1 = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();
 $fp = fopen('/path/to/file/output.txt',w);
 fwrite($fp,$out1);
 fclose($fp);
 echo'<pre>', $out1,'</pre>';
 #var_dump($out1);
 ?>
```

Please suggest me what is wrong with the long TCl scrip.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407939/shell-exec-timeout-management-exec. Your script might be timing out.

Comment: You've shown no evidence that the problem lies in the helloworld script. A google search for "php passthru timeout" reveals some relevant SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
For long running scripts (like daemons) i recommend using popen and stream the content out of the resource.

Example:

```
<?php
$h = popen('./test.sh', 'r');                                                                                                                                                        
while (($read = fread($h, 2096)) ) {                                                                                                                                                 
    echo $read;
    sleep(1);                                                                                                                                                                        
}
pclose($h);
```

You should check your php.ini for the "max_execution_time". If you are in a webserver context also check for configured timeouts there.

END OF EDIT

Have you tried [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php)

The second parameter is a reference to an array which gets filled with the scripts output

in short:

```
<?php
$output = array();
exec('/path/to/file/helloworld', $output);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file/output.txt', implode("\n", $output));
```

Example:

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                          
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz";                                                                                                                                                             
echo -e "1\n2\n3";
```

test.php:

```
<?php

$output = array();
exec('./test.sh', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

output:

```
php test.php
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "baz"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

Quote of the official php documentation (link see above)

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled **with every line of output from the command**.

Comment: `exec` only returns the last line of output. `passthru` is correct in this case. (I've undone my downvote since you're new.)

Comment: @acheong87 it returns only last line, but here no return is stored. `$output` is passed as reference and filled with every line.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller - Ah, sorry, yeah, I didn't see that. I'm pretty sure this user posted the same question yesterday, and he was using `exec`, so I jumped to the conclusion that someone was suggesting back to `exec`. I think his problem really is a timeout though.

Comment: So anyone is having any idea that how to proceed with timeout for the long script. any example would be the great help !!