# set time limit on java code execution through shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, shell, command-line, kill-process

I have developed an online java code editor at http://joomla5.guru99.com/try-java-editor.html I am invoking javac using shell_exec function of php and executing java code.

```
$result = shell_exec('javac' .$soucejavafile. '2>&1');
and running classfile by
$result= shell_exec('java' .$classfile. '2>&1');
```

Now for security purpose, I want to set time limit for this java code execution. For example, java code execution should be stopped after some amount time and all it's processes must be killed

I have tried 
ulimit and ps commands but couldn't able to achieve this.

Please assist me in the correct direction and please help me to make this possible.

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell\_exec() timeout management & exec()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407939/shell-exec-timeout-management-exec)

Comment: @WesleyBland both are entirely different as i'm invoking java processes using shell_exec but not using proc_open which he is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 3 ways:

1) Call [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) in PHP and check the timeout in parent process. Kill it if it exceeds using linux kill command.

2) Include timeout in a bash script that you will invoke using shell_exec, see this example:
http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.0/examples/scripts/timeout3

3) Use [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) / [proc_terminate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php) functions

Personally I would go with number 3, it's the cleanest. If you need quick and dirty, use number 2.