# How can I enforce a time limit on a call to `exec()`?

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to make an online judge written PHP. My code currently looks like:

```
exec("gcc /var/www/qwerty.c -o /var/www/binary",$output,$returnval);
print_r($output);
exec("cat /var/www/qwe.txt | /var/www/binary",$output,$returnval);
print_r($output);
```

However, I want each process spawned by `exec` to have at most 1 second to run. I'm not sure how to do this.
set_time_limit() isn't working

Comment: Witness, if you will, my improvement to the question title.

Comment: @ManseUK: Read that very page: `The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real. `

Comment: I've edited your post to make what I think you want clearer. The question now is, what do you want to happen if the process takes more than 1 second?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit comment removed !!!! ta

Comment: Closers: No, no, no. This is a real question. It might have been badly phrased originally, but I think with an edit or two and a comment, the real issue can easily be brought out.

Comment: @AdamWright: If nothing else, it's an obvious dup of a lot of previous questions (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603912/php-set-timeout-for-script-with-system-call-set-time-limit-not-working, more or less), and it shows absolutely no prior research. The fact is, it may be a real problem for the OP, but this is not a real _question_ for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Last comment by me (as this is meta discussion), but if you think it's a dupe, close a dupe. Not as "Not a real question".

Answer (score 8):

I would use the [`proc_`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) functions as suggested by @Adam Wright, but a quick alternative to Linux-like environments is to use the GNU `timeout` command before your command:

```
// If it took more than 1 second, $returnval will got the exit code 124
exec('timeout 1 gcc /var/www/qwerty.c -o /var/www/binary', $output, $returnval);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can probably use [`ulimit`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) for that:

```
exec(" ( ulimit -t 1 ; gcc ... | /var/www/binary) ");
```

That of course only works if the process uses active CPU time, not if it waits for I/O endlessly.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using the [`proc_`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) family of functions. Launch your processes using `proc_open`. Repeatedly poll using `proc_status` (with some small sleep in-between polls) until either the process has returned or 1 second has passed. If 1 second passes without `proc_status` indicating the process has finished, use `proc_terminate` (or `proc_close`) to kill it off, and take appropriate action.

I'm not saying that spawning external processes in a PHP script is a good idea, though.