# PHP exec() - set execution time limit?

Tags: php, time, exec, kill, execution

I use PHP `exec()` function to make system calls on windows env.

Now, I want to make sure that if i make a call, it doesnt go on forever.  I want to kill the process after `$x` seconds.  For example:

```
exec('2.exe');
```

If `2.exe` runs for more than 15 seconds, kill 2.exe.

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202355/maximum-execution-time-of-60-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176497/limit-execution-time-of-an-function-or-command-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enforce a time limit on a call to `exec()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128938/how-can-i-enforce-a-time-limit-on-a-call-to-exec/9128994#9128994) - which explains actual ways to constrain exec.

Comment: already went through those posts.. the set_time_limit doesnt seem to work.. and i'm not very sure how to use proc functions..

Comment: What is your operating system? Windows?